# Auto resolving stack overflow 'share' links

Tags: feature-request, sharing

I find it not infrequent that I refer people to:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

If I paste it as a raw URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454
```

Stack Overflow recognises it, and auto-linkifies. However if I'm looking to link to a specific *answer* and select the 'share' button by it, I get a URL of:
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2566198`

Which when pasted, is *not* automatically handled by SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2566198

Is this difficult to change, and could it be? (As a workaround, following the 'short' link and pasting the resultant URL works)

Comment: Should I accept at 'that solved my problem' given it is a dupe, but it is unanswered?

Comment: Answers aren't resolved because the answers themselves don't have titles; the questions do.

Comment: Both links I post point to the same answer to a specific question. One resolves to the question title, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

[Auto resolving stack overflow 'share' links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287914/289086) - are you *sure* that is the case?

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287914/289086 - are you *sure* that is the case?
```

Though https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287915/289086 answers appear to be different.

```
Though https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287915/289086 answers appear to be different.
```

([raw source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4d083320-b658-439e-a6e4-9eb39299e7f1/view-source))

Comment: Interesting. OK, so the top levels of posts work, but answer resolving doesn't. (My second link is a literal paste of the result).